# Two output file names resolved to the same output path

Tags: resources, visual-studio-2013, telerik-reporting

I have a project in VS2013, where I use the report from Telerik.
In the solution I have one report and a few classes. If I copy the first report rename it, Visual Studio reports error:

```
Two output file names resolved to the same output path: "obj\Debug\...
```

If I Remove the copied report and try to through the wizard add a new report to project, VS report me the same error.

Do you have someone with experience and someone you do not know the solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this error when using entity frameworks code first migrations and had the same name for two of my migrations in the Migrations folder.

`Two output file names resolved to the same output path: "obj\Debug\***.resources`

I deleted the duplicate migration.cs file and the error went away. running add-migration again with the same name brought it back.

Answer (score 1):

I had three files for a userControl, all sharing a common partial class, and this caused my issue; they were named ucPlate.cs, ucPlate.Map.cs, and ucPlate.Graphics.cs. When I changed ucPlate.Graphics userControl surface to DoubleBuffered, I got the compilation error, "Error  21  Two output file names resolved to the same output path: "obj\Debug\ASMS.Controls.ucPlate.resources" Reverting to DoubleBuffered = false did not fix it, nor did deleting the .resx file that was created when I turned on DoubleBuffered (previously, there was no .resx file).

The root cause was that turning on DoubleBuffered in the subsidiary partial class file auto-added InitializeComponent() to the bottom of my code for that file.  This method indicated the duplicate ucPlate name, forcing a .resx creation that already existed for the ucPlate.cs file.  I had expected it to be ucPlate.Graphics.resx.

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // ucPlate
    // 
    this.Name = "ucPlate";
    this.ResumeLayout(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

go to the solution explorer (if you rename a form e try to look at your error and delete the `.resx` file that have in your error)